# vb.net: index out of range

Tags: vb.net

```
Public extreme_foods As New System.Collections.ArrayList()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

For Each s In split2
    extreme_foods(i) = s
    i = i + 1
Next
```

anyone know why extreme_foods(i)=s is giving INDEX OUT OF RANGE??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because there are no items in it. try `extreme_foods.Add(s)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code, you're trying to add elements to the ArrayList.  I think you'd want to use the Add() method.  So something like:

```
For Each s In split2
    extreme_foods.Add(s)
Next
```

I'm assuming that split2 is a Collection you've created somewhere else in your code.